# When can we replace a matrix by its eigenvalues in an integral?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have the following integral I wish to compute:
\begin{equation}
Z=\int\left( \prod_i \mathrm{d}\phi_i \right)\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j} J_{i j} \cos(\phi_{i}) \cos(\phi_{j})-h \sum_{i} \cos(\phi_{i})\right\}
\end{equation}

I know all the eigenvalues of the matrix $\mathbf{J}$: Am I allowed to replace $J_{ij}$ by its eigenvalues $\lambda_j$?

**Can I express the integral $Z$ as follows?**
\begin{equation}
Z=\int\left( \prod_i \mathrm{d}\phi_i \right)\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j} \lambda_j \cos(\phi_{i}) \cos(\phi_{j})-h \sum_{i} \cos(\phi_{i})\right\}
\end{equation}

Is this correct? Or do I need to add some constant in front of the integral, or does it get more complicated than that?

Comment: **J** looks like a covariance matrix. Is it symmetric positive-definite?

Comment: Yes we can assume it is